# RESTeasy return different character encoding JSON(P)

Tags: java, character-encoding, resteasy

Does anybody know a way to enable response character set selection by client for RESTeasy? I'm working with 1.2.1GA. My responses return UTF-8 although I'm not sure why and where that is defined because my test system's default encoding in java is CP1252-something and the annotations looked like that:

```
@GET
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML } )
```

I tried to vary these MediaTypes with no success.

```
// Add another media type
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, "application/json;charset=iso-8859-1" } )

// Try to always return latin-1 JSON. TESTING ONLY!!!
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=iso-8859-1", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML } )
```

I request with REST Client for Firefox setting the charset in the *accept* and *accept-encoding* headers and still I always get UTF-8 JSON. But the client that needs the data is going to be included in a latin-1 web page, which is quite... you know. I can't influence that. I'd like to avoid re-encoding that all manually in JavaScript. In addition the serverside solution seems much more solid to me.

I also tried some other stuff which I was never really expecting to work, like changing response character encoding with a servlet filter and so on. (Necessity is the mother of invention. ^^)

Google/the web don't have much to offer on this topic so after hours of trying I now come here and hope somebody might tell me how this is intended to work or if it's even possible.

So long, regards

S.Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically reencoding the returned response is not supported yet: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-465

It seems that there is limited support when using JAX-B return types though: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-269